# Add column to dataframe from .apply

Tags: python, pandas

I have a small issue manipulating a dataframe to create a new variable function of others.

I am able to calculate it but no to agregate it back to the original dataframe.

Here I have my `test` dataframe and my `new_column`

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'name': ["john", "jack", "albert"],
                         'day': ["2018-01-01", "2018-01-02", "2018-01-03"],
                         'result': ['c("7", "6", "")', 'c("3", "6", "10")', 'c("4", "3", "")']})

def update_result(row, x):
    return row[x].replace("c(", "").replace(")","").replace("\"","").replace(" ","").split(",")

new_column=test.apply(lambda row: update_result(row,2),axis=1)
```

But when I try to add the `new_column` to the data_frame I got an error message about manipulating a copy. Do you know what would be the correct way to agregate this column ?

```
test['result2']=new_column
```

I got:

```
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 3, placement implies 1
```

and

```
 # check if we are modifying a copy
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hmmm, the `c()` seems to suggested the atomic vector in R!

Comment: that's right ! ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to apply a function to a specific column you could try it this way:

```
test['result2']=test['result'].apply(lambda row: row.replace("c(", "").replace(")","").replace("\"","").replace(" ","").split(","))

Out[5]:
          day    name             result     result2
0  2018-01-01    john    c("7", "6", "")    [7, 6, ]
1  2018-01-02    jack  c("3", "6", "10")  [3, 6, 10]
2  2018-01-03  albert    c("4", "3", "")    [4, 3, ]
```

In case a `SettingWithCopyWarning` warning shows up you can try to set or update the column as suggested:

```
new_col=test['result'].apply(lambda row: row.replace("c(", "").replace(")","").replace("\"","").replace(" ","").split(","))
test.loc[:, 'result2'] = new_col
```

The **loc** commands require specifying which rows you want to select (**:** means all rows) and which column (*result2* is the name of the column you want to create or if you want to update an existing one such as *result* you can as well).

You could also check this page, this topic is well explained [here](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/settingwithcopywarning/).

Comment: Thanks a lot @Milton, this work in deed, but in Jupyter I got a warning (the same as with Parfait solution), Do you know why?

SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: Basically, that warning says that you are modifying a subset of your original dataframe. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 2):

No need for `apply` which is a loop. Consider directly assigning column using the vectorized [Series.str](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.html) method. Also, you can use regex in `str.replace` to extract all numbers and commas and avoid the long chaining.

```
test['res1'] = test['result'].str.replace("c\(", "")\
                             .str.replace("\)","").str.replace("\"","")\
                             .str.replace(" ","").str.split(",")

test['res2'] = test['result'].str.replace(r'[^0-9,]', '').str.split(",")
print(test)

#           day    name             result        res1        res2
# 0  2018-01-01    john    c("7", "6", "")    [7, 6, ]    [7, 6, ]
# 1  2018-01-02    jack  c("3", "6", "10")  [3, 6, 10]  [3, 6, 10]
# 2  2018-01-03  albert    c("4", "3", "")    [4, 3, ]    [4, 3, ]
```

Comment: Thank you @Parfait, that's a nice solution but I got a warning using this in Jupyter:
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Doyou know why?

Comment: Assign column with `loc`: test.loc[:,'res1']=... and check if warning appears outside Jupyter like command line script.

Answer (score 0):

The assignment operation won't work, because you are assigning a DataFrame to a column (expecting a Series):

[image]

Try asking for the specific column instead:

```
new_column=test['result'].apply(lambda row: row.replace("c(", "").replace(")","").replace("\"","").replace(" ","").split(","))    
test['result2']=new_column
```

P.S. just saw that someone else posted pretty much the same answer before me, but I'd put mine here anyway.